# What's the shortcut to add emojis in Google Docs text comments?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-docs, emoji

Talking about adding emojis to text comments. How do I access the emoji drop down menu by keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type a colon followed by the name of the emoji to get the shortlist.

```
: + 'name of emoji'
```

Comment: This is correct within the doc itself; but not within a comment field.

Answer (score 0):

... While you need to do the special colon thing as mentioned by Ansjovis86 in his (unfortunately incorrect) answer *within the doc itself*... **the default OS emoji shortcut** actually does work in the *comment field* (at least for Mac)!

That would be **command+control+space** on Mac.

I'm assuming/hoping it would be the same for Windows—which is the **Windows key+period**.